# Get the Clojurescript repl/connect to not compile when in production?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In my clojurescript code I have the following:

```
(defn onload [] (repl/connect "http://localhost:9000/repl"))

(set! (.-onload js/window) onload)
```

The Clojurescript repl is very useful in development, but I am hesitant to leave it in the code during production. What is the cleanest way to have the above code present during development (simple compilation), but absent during production (advanced compilation)?

Answer (score 7):

The [modern-cljs](https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs) tutorial actually describes exactly how to solve this [here](https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs/blob/master/doc/first-edition/tutorial-07.md#getting-in-trouble).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there aren't currently any well defined ways to do conditional compilation in ClojureScript.

You could add configuration variables to control whether to start a REPL in a variety of ways, but one quick and easy way would be to get the hostname of the current page, and only invoke `repl/connnect` if it was "localhost" or whatever other domains you're using for development work.

Comment: Thinking out loud, that would also mean that all the code for repl/connect would also end up being compiled into my production code. I honestly have no idea how large that compiled segment is, just making a point.

Answer (score 1):

I think a combination of lein2 profiles and cljsbuild src-paths munging can do the trick.  eg, create a namespace that simply loads your repl, and exclude it with a profile run for the final compile (possibly might need to create a dummy namespace in another src-path directory).